# The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

I suddenly start having error in project. all csproj files are correct and all packages are up to date.

I am working with .net core 5. I have folder structure like below.

Project
Project core
Project business
Project infrastructure

Would you please help me solve this?

Here is the error list

[image]

Thank You

Comment: I suspect you recently updated one of the source files that hasn't been compiled in a long time and was using a different version of Net.  Core is a single library that doesn't have all the libraries that Net has.  Sometimes you need to add additional libraries to Core. I would start by using Solution Explorer and check that all the references are valid.

Comment: The issue with one file wrongly added. Thanks. As i checked for files, it resolved it. Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I could not be able to reproduce the problem, but I believe adding this to your project file will solve the problem:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectCapability Include="SupportsSystemWeb" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I have already tried this. It is not working. Thank You.

Comment: will you please post your .csproj here?

Comment: It was not issue with csproj. I had misplaced the file that was the issue. It is resolved. I appreciate your help. Thank You.